# Synergy with 6 screens, how do I setup config

Tags: synergy, configure

I have 6 screens, 2 rows of 3.
My bottom layer of 3 screens are one computer (windows 7)
Top left is my Mac
Top Middle is Windows 10
Top Right is linux

Currently my Synergy setup is just like a T

```
MAC - Win 10 - Linux

      Win 7
```

I cannot use my windows 7 far right screen to go up to Linux, I have to go to the center Win 7, up to Win 10 and then right to Linux, is there a way to setup the Synergy setup to do this properly.
My current config is as below

```
section: screens
WIN10:
    halfDuplexCapsLock = false
    halfDuplexNumLock = false
    halfDuplexScrollLock = false
    xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
    switchCorners = none 
    switchCornerSize = 0
james-linux:
    halfDuplexCapsLock = false
    halfDuplexNumLock = false
    halfDuplexScrollLock = false
    xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
    switchCorners = none 
    switchCornerSize = 0
WIN7:
    halfDuplexCapsLock = false
    halfDuplexNumLock = false
    halfDuplexScrollLock = false
    xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
    switchCorners = none 
    switchCornerSize = 0
```

end

```
section: aliases
end

section: links
WIN10:
    right = james-linux
    down = WIN7
james-linux:
    left = WIN10
WIN7:
    up = WIN10
end

section: options
 relativeMouseMoves = false
 screenSaverSync = true
 win32KeepForeground = false
 switchCorners = none 
 switchCornerSize = 0
end
```

Any help would be awesome

Cheers

James

Answer (score 0):

You have an `up` option for `WIN7` but no `right` option, so when you try to go to the right nothing will happen.

These `up`, `left`, etc. options are not the locations of the screens, they are what machine you want to jump to when you cursor off that edge.